# React menu best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React, and I'm building out a dropdown navigation menu that toggles on hover. I need to know what best practices would be for toggling this menu.

Currently I'm using state to toggle a `data` attribute that I can reference in the CSS i.e. `data-menu="open"` for the mobile menu. Should I be doing it this way, or should I use state to toggle the menu open and closed?

Thanks in advance, I'd love anyone's input here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use react for that you could just use an `:hover` css selector

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: Great, that's what I figured. I was just verifying that that was consistent with best practices!